# Rotate image changing properties phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to rotate a image that I capture from the camera or gallery. The steps are:

1. You capture the image from the camera or gallery You have the
2. possibility to rotate the image for after crop the image.

I try to rotate the image with CSS properties, the image is rotated well, but the original properties from the image don't change so the problem is that when I call to crop, the crop option choose from the original image, not from the rotate image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use "correctOrientation" property and set the height and width of the image . This will help you